# Custom datetime picker not working - Android

Tags: android, datetimepicker

I'm using a custom `datetimepicker` for an android app.
I installed dependency as:

> implementation 'com.github.noowenz:CustomDateTimePicker:1.01'

Then I added it in my `activity` as follows:

```
final static String TAG = BookcabActivity.class.getCanonicalName();
Calendar selectedDateAndTime = Calendar.getInstance();
mTextViewOne = findViewById(R.id.et_datetime);
        mTextViewOne.setFocusable(false);
        mTextViewOne.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            show_Datepicker();
        });
private void show_Datepicker() {
        new CustomDateTimePicker(this, new CustomDateTimePicker.ICustomDateTimeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSet(@NotNull Dialog dialog, @NotNull Calendar calendar,
                              @NotNull Date date, int year, @NotNull String monthFullName,
                              @NotNull String monthShortName, int monthNumber, int day,
                              @NotNull String weekDayFullName, @NotNull String weekDayShortName,
                              int hour24, int hour12, int min, int sec, @NotNull String AM_PM) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Date and time selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                selectedDateAndTime = calendar;
                String dateAndTime = "Date is" + date + "Year is" + year + "Day is" + day;
                Log.d(TAG, "onSet: Date is" + dateAndTime);
                mTextViewOne.setText(dateAndTime);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Date and Time selection is cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

But datetime dialog doesn't pop up, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `.showDialog()`

Try this:

```
private void show_Datepicker() {
        new CustomDateTimePicker(this, new CustomDateTimePicker.ICustomDateTimeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSet(@NotNull Dialog dialog, @NotNull Calendar calendar,
                              @NotNull Date date, int year, @NotNull String monthFullName,
                              @NotNull String monthShortName, int monthNumber, int day,
                              @NotNull String weekDayFullName, @NotNull String weekDayShortName,
                              int hour24, int hour12, int min, int sec, @NotNull String AM_PM) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Date and time selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                selectedDateAndTime = calendar;
                String dateAndTime = "Date is" + date + "Year is" + year + "Day is" + day;
                Log.d(TAG, "onSet: Date is" + dateAndTime);
                mTextViewOne.setText(dateAndTime);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Date and Time selection is cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).showDialog();

    }
```